# reprojecting a satellite image in Python

Tags: python, image, gdal, coordinate

I'm looking for a command in Python to reproject an image. I know that it could be done with GDALWARP in command line of windows and can be called from within Python using os module, but I wanted to know if there is a native python command for it or not.

Thank you,
Farzin

Comment: StackExchange as a Geographic Informations Systems [site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) for you.  And perhaps a relevant answer: [Converting projected geoTiff to WGS84 with GDAL and Python](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/converting-projected-geotiff-to-wgs84-with-gdal-and-python).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to do [arbitrary affine transformations](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#Image.transform). As far as I know though, there are no core Python modules for image manipulation. If you are already comfortable using `GDALWARP` I would stick with that, personally.